# USB keyboard randomly stops working (can't reset device error: -32)

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, input

Once in a while (extremely rarely, maybe once every few months), my keyboard stops accepting input, seemingly randomly. The mouse is dragged down at the same time.

What I tried initially:

- Unplugging the keyboard, changing USB ports, etc.
- Killing X to see if it was just an X problem. - It still didn't work in the TTY.

Here is the dmesg output:

```
[292577.664739] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 127 using ehci-pci
[292765.597248] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 126
[292765.864838] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[292765.995452] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input231
[292765.995818] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00BB: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[292766.019378] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input232
[292766.019601] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00BC: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[292766.877067] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[292767.184498] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[292767.315004] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input233
[292767.315266] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00BD: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[292767.339019] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input234
[292767.339218] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00BE: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[292775.067103] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[292775.409392] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[292775.530241] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input235
[292775.530617] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00BF: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[292775.555411] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input236
[292775.555760] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C0: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[293151.301660] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[293151.602963] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[293151.733736] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input237
[293151.734142] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C1: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[293151.758862] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input238
[293151.759163] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C2: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[297657.924755] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
[297658.200020] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[297658.330960] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input239
[297658.331367] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C3: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[297658.356081] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input240
[297658.356397] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C4: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[299406.263472] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[299406.585688] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[299406.962387] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[299407.438783] usb 2-1.4: device not accepting address 9, error -32
[299407.639031] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[299407.770011] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input241
[299407.770374] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C5: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[299408.002391] usbhid 2-1.4:1.1: can't add hid device: -32
[299408.002415] usbhid: probe of 2-1.4:1.1 failed with error -32
[299482.821097] systemd-journald[127]: Deleted empty journal /var/log/journal/9dfdf17424bafdda5523332b0000024a/user-1000@0004eb8aefaaa397-d7ec408d561b38c9.journal~ (3735552 bytes).
[299483.502112] systemd-journald[127]: Vacuuming done, freed 3735552 bytes
[299483.914891] systemd-journald[127]: Failed to write entry (26 items, 686162541 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: Argument list too long
[299486.082253] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C5: can't reset device, 0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0, status -32
[299486.117301] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 11
[299488.861814] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[299488.982663] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input242
[299488.983060] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C6: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[299489.200457] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input243
[299489.200836] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C7: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[299492.994681] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C6: can't reset device, 0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0, status -32
[299493.027451] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 12
[299493.089566] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C7: can't reset device, 0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1, status -32
[299495.260316] usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[299495.381214] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input244
[299495.381622] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C8: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[299495.599013] input: CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input245
[299495.599400] hid-generic 0003:2516:0004.00C9: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/
```

Also, I am running kernel 3.12.2-1 on Arch Linux.

UPDATE: I tried swapping it with another keyboard (same model), and am still experiencing issues.

Next I am going to try using a different cord.

UPDATE 2: I tried using a new cord, and haven't been experiencing any problems.

Comment: Have you tried a different (known-good) keyboard yet?

Comment: No, but I have another one (same model) that it hasn't happened to, so I could try swapping and see what happens.. I will post an update.